# data binding non-strings to TextBox.Text (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, textbox

I'm storing a whole bunch of settings for my winforms program in various .settings files.
Included in these settings are `System.Drawing.Point`, `System.Drawing.Location`, `System.TimeSpan`, `System.DateTime`, etc...

When I bind a form's `Location` to a `System.Drawing.Location`, and call the `.Save()` method, it all seems to work fine. That is, since there doesn't seem to be a need for a cast, the form's `System.Drawing.Location` is directly compatible with the `System.Drawing.Location` setting stored in the .settings file.
Additionally, if I say `TimeSpan timeSpan = Settings.Duration;` that also works fine.

Now, I have made a large settings form, where the user can adjust various parameters, including the various `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` settings. These are visible and editable in many `TextBox`, which I have data bound in the following way:

```
Settings DefaultSettings = Settings.Default;
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(("Text", DefaultSettings, "Duration", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, new TimeSpan(00, 30, 00));
```

The `TimeSpan` is visible in the `TextBox`, however when I try to edit it and call `Save()` on the settings data source, I get the following error:

> Value of '0' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'Minimum' and 'Maximum'.
>   Parameter name: Value

The error originates from the Visual Studio generated code block:

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("00:30:00")]
public global::System.TimeSpan StartWorkDay {
  get {
    return ((global::System.TimeSpan)(this["Duration"]));
  }
  set {
    this["Duration"] = value;
  }
}
```

I think the problem is caused by the fact that it's trying to turn a string into a `System.TimeSpan`, and the various other classes I have in my .settings file.

Since I'm binding them using the `DataBindings.Add(` which accepts strings for the parameters, I can't cast or use the new keyword there.

I *could* handle it all manually in code: updating the settings file by constructing the objects parameter-by-parameter, but I have so many settings stored in so many TextBoxes and NumericUpDowns that I would prefer to just bind them straight to the `TextBox`, assuming that's possible.

What is the easiest way I can achieve this?

Comment: You should add a tag to WinForms, asp.net, WPF or whatever technology you are using.  This question has very little to do with c# and most everything to do with your presentation technology.

Comment: I just edited it to show that it's WinForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following code in a sample windows form application and it did the save without any exceptions.

```
// Define the settings binding source
private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource settingsBindingSource;

 private void InitializeComponent()
  {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.durationTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.settingsBindingSource = new BindingSource(this.components);
            this.settingsBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings);
            this.durationTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.settingsBindingSource, "Duration", true));
  }

// In the form load event where the textbox is displayed
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   settingsBindingSource.DataSource = Settings.Default;
}

// save button click
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // This saved the settings, without any exceptions
   Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could declare a “conversion property” (I just invented that term) in the `Settings` class:

```
public class Settings
{
    // The real property
    public TimeSpan StartWorkDay { get; set; }

    // The conversion property
    public string StartWorkDayString
    {
        get
        {
            return StartWorkDay.ToString();
            // (or use .ToString("...") to format it)
        }
        set
        {
            StartWorkDay = TimeSpan.Parse(value);
            // (or use TryParse() to avoid throwing exceptions)
        }
    }
}
```

... and then bind the textbox to that.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a somewhat-elegant solution which you might be interested in:

Since the problem seemed to be that I was unable to cast or construct the data types I had in the .settings file from simple text boxes as I was using data binding, I instead made some custom controls.

For example, the TimeSpans now use a `TimeSpanPicker` which I made out of a `DateTimePicker` control, with the date disabled, the up/down toggles on, and the `Value` property is converted to a TimeSpan from within the picker control.

The added advantage of this method is that I don't need to do a lot of the validation I needed to before with text boxes, as the TimeSpanPicker base control DateTimePicker will only show valid times. What little validation I do need to do can be done in the Set{} property, so I don't need to define event handlers.

This seems to be working well!
Now all I need to do is replace all the text boxes with custom controls.